# Is there a way to get ipython functionality for a jython command line?

Tags: ipython, jython

I saw that there's a project `ijython` (https://github.com/graphaelli/ijython.git), but it doesn't say what it does and refers to the ipython project page where is no information about the project. The development stopped 4 years ago according to commit messages, so I won't bother with that, exept someone recommends and explains it. I was wondering whether there might a way to acchieve `jython` to behave like an `ipython` shell setting up a configuration file of either `jython` or `ipython`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython almost support jython kernel cf https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6213 for example (among others). Once the next jython release is out of beta, we'll be happy to include the patches to make it work.